# RTMP restreaming via Youtube

Tags: youtube, live-streaming

I can able to stream live events using FMLE encoder in Youtube and Is there any possibilities to restream an existing RTMP stream using Youtube.

I'm new to Youtube streaming! So please correct me if I'm wrong.